# Xml deserialization with nested tags not working

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

I need to deserialize a XML file to a object. Following is the XML content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<PdfFile>
  <PageTitle DocumentName="Sequence Diagram" Version="Version 4" >Title</PageTitle>
  <LogoPath>C:\logo.png</LogoPath>
  <Modules>
    <Module Id="1" MainTitle="Module1">
      <SubModules>
        <SubModule>
          <Title>SubModule1</Title>
          <Path>SubModule1 Path</Path>
          <Description>SubModule1 Desc</Description>
        </SubModule>
        <SubModule>
          <Title>SubModule2</Title>
          <Path>SubModule2 Path</Path>
          <Description>SubModule2 Desc</Description>
        </SubModule>
      </SubModules>
    </Module>
    <Module Id="2" MainTitle="Module2">
      <SubModules>
         <SubModule>
           <Title>SubModule1</Title>
           <Path>SubModule1 Path</Path>
           <Description>SubModule1 Desc</Description>
         </SubModule>
      </SubModules>
    </Module>
  </Modules>
</PdfFile>
```

Following is the class file I created, for the above xml file.

```
    using System;
    using System.Xml.Serialization;

    namespace PDFCreation.Objects
    {

        [Serializable]
        [XmlRoot("PdfFile")]
        public class PdfFile2
        {
            [XmlElement("PageTitle")]
            public PageTitle FirstPage { get; set; }

            [XmlElement("LogoPath")]
            public string LogoPath { get; set; }

            [XmlArray("Modules")]
            [XmlArrayItem("Module", typeof(Module))]
            public Module[] Modules { get; set; }

        } 

        [Serializable]
        public class Module
        {
            [XmlAttributeAttribute("Id")]
            public int Id { get; set; }

            [XmlAttributeAttribute("MainTitle")]
            public string MainTitle { get; set; }

            [XmlArray("SubModules")]
            [XmlArrayItem("SubModule", typeof(SubModule))]
            public SubModule[] Modules { get; set; }
        } 

        [Serializable]
        public class SubModule
        {
            [XmlElement("Title")]
            public string Title { get; set; }

            [XmlElement("Path")]
            public string Path { get; set; }

            [XmlElement("Description")]
            public string Description { get; set; }
        }

        [Serializable]
        public class PageTitle
        {
            [XmlText]
            public string Title { get; set; }

            [XmlAttribute]
            public string DocumentName { get; set; }

            [XmlAttribute]
            public string Version { get; set; }
        }

     }
```

On deserializing, I'm not getting any error. But the modules inside PdfFile object always returns null. I tried to use the generated class from xsd.exe. But still the same thing is happening.

Please help me to find issue in the code/xml and why it is not deserializing fully?

Thanks!!!

Edited:

My C# code:

```
  public class Program
{
    private static readonly string XmlPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["XmlPath"];

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            ReadXml();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    private static void ReadXml()
    {
        if (!File.Exists(XmlPath))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: Xml File Not exists in the path: {0}", XmlPath);
            return;
        }

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(XmlPath))
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PdfFile2));
            var result = (PdfFile2)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

            //other code here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that the full XML? It seems to be missing the closing tags for `</Modules></PdfFile>`

Comment: other than the closing tags (as pointed out above) all looks to be fine. Can you show your deserialization code?

Comment: sorry! formatted xml correctly and added deserialization code. Thanks for pointing it.

Comment: Yes all looks to be fine. Even it deserializing without any error. But in debug mode, if you try to look the result object, you can find "Modules" as null. That's the problem.

Comment: This doesn't happen for me. As I wrote in my answer it deserializes all the objects in the xml. What version of .Net are you running on?

Comment: Never mind about the version I just tried it out with 2.0,3.5 and 4.0 and it work flawless on all versions with your updated code.  And have you checked that you are pointing your reader to the right file? Don't be offended if you have, but lets rule out the obvious mistakes first.

Comment: I'm using 4.0 version. Did you try with my code?

Comment: did you see my previous comment? It came in right before you submitteed your own.

Comment: thanks falle!!! working now. changed the path from "C:\Users\ani\Documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\PDFCreation\PDFCreation\test.xml" to "F:\PdfCreation\test.xml" and used your code instead of streamreader

Comment: Happy to hear you found the problem  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using nothing but you supplied code/xml and putting in the missing closing tags I got it to deserialize using this Main-class:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using PDFCreation.Objects;

public class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PdfFile2));
        PdfFile2 pdf = (PdfFile2)ser.Deserialize(File.OpenRead("test.xml"));
    }
}
```

What does your deserialization code look like?